# MySQL get first row value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My whole query works apart from this sub query:

```
"(SELECT a.NumSeats From Aircrafts a WHERE f.AircraftID =a.AircrafID)"
```

I want that to return a number e.g 5

As I am selecting a.NumSeats which is an integer I can't understand why this doesn't work.

Also this query will return a MAX of 1 row.

```
$subQuery1 = "(SELECT COUNT(*) from Seats s WHERE s.FlightID = f.FlightID)";
    $subQuery2 = "(SELECT a.NumSeats From Aircrafts a WHERE f.AircraftID =a.AircrafID)";
    $subQuery2 = 0;
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Flights f WHERE f.DeptAirport = '".$dep."' AND f.ArrAirport = '".$arr.
            "' AND f.Date=STR_TO_DATE('".$depDate."', '%Y-%m-%d') AND ".$subQuery1. "=" .$subQuery2);
```

If i remove $subQuery2 = 0 it breaks

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: Your table for `f` is missing.

Comment: See update please should help

Comment: Should `a.AircrafID` be `a.AircraftID`?

Comment: Yes! Thank god for that! Please post as question and ill accept

Comment: Can you please, for your own safety, stop using `mysql_query`? You're probably exposed to several severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because you're not using [SQL placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Comment: All varibles are done with mysql_real_escape_string does that help?

Comment: It's a bit better than without but you should still use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Im using xamp though it doesnt work with mysqli sadly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `a.AircrafID` should be `a.AircraftID`.